# How to simplify this triple summation containing binomial coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

> $$
>   \large\sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{j=i}^{n} \sum_{k=j}^{n} 
>     \binom{i+m-1}{m-1}\binom{j+m-1}{m-1}\binom{k+m-1}{m-1}
> $$

How to solve it when this involve more than thousand summation ?

Comment: Write a program to do it. Do you have reason to believe that there is a clever way to find this sum without just cranking it out? Also, what is $m$, and why not just let $u = m-1$ or something to make the summation look a bit less scary?

Comment: This is similar to the recent question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313543/how-to-solve-this-multiple-summation) which has not yet been answered at the time of this comment.

Comment: The solution would be a nice and neat one (and probably easily extended to a thousand summations) if the summand is only $\binom {i+m-1}{m-1}$, in which case the summation would read:
$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{j=i}^{n} \sum_{k=j}^{n} \binom{i+m-1}{m-1}\\
&=\sum_{0\leq i\leq j\leq k\leq n}\binom{i+m-1}{m-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^k \sum_{i=0}^j\binom{i+m-1}{m-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^k  \binom {j+m}m\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom {k+m+1}{m+1}\\
&=\binom {n+m+2}{m+2}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

**First step**. write a little script to see what we have.

The following GNU Maxima script, with an extra factor $n!(m+2)!/(n+m+2)!$

```
display2d : false;

load("interpol");

for m : 1 thru 6 do block(
        h : makelist(
                sum(sum(sum(
                        1
                        *binomial(i+m-1,m-1)
                        *binomial(j+m-1,m-1)
                        *binomial(k+m-1,m-1)
                        *n!*(m+2)!/(n+m+2)!
                ,k,j,n),j,i,n),i,0,n),n,1,40),
        fmn : factor(lagrange(h,varname='n)),
        print(m,fmn)
);
```

gives

$m=1$: $f(1,n)=1$

$m=2$:
$f(2,n)=(n+1)(n+2)/2$

$m=3$:
$f(3,n)=(35n^4+294n^3+844n^2+969n+378)/378$

$m=4$:
$f(4,n)=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(35n^2+205n+168)/4032$

$m=5$:
$f(5,n)=(3003n^8+76076n^7+804496n^6+4613510n^5+15604357n^4+31707374n^3
          +37643584n^2+23833200n+6177600)
  /6177600$

$m=6$:
$f(6,n)=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(77n^4+1218n^3+6202n^2+10983n+5940)
  /4276800$

We have as leading terms $n^{2(m-1)}\cdot(m+1)(m+2)/m!/m!/6$.

**Second step**.
These sums all have a constant term equalling $1$. This and the form
of the triple sum containing only binomials suggests to search for a hypergeometric representation.

**Third step**.
Try to find a rigorous proof.

**Interlude with double sums**.
But wait, why not try the same program with the double sum variant?

The following GNU Maxima script, with an extra factor $n!(m+1)!/(n+m+1)!$

```
display2d : false;

load("interpol");

for m : 1 thru 7 do block(
        h : makelist(
                sum(sum(
                        1
                        *binomial(i+m-1,m-1)
                        *binomial(j+m-1,m-1)
                        *n!*(m+1)!/(n+m+1)!
                ,j,i,n),i,0,n),n,1,40),
        fmn : factor(lagrange(h,varname='n)),
        print(m,fmn)
);
```

gives

$m=1$:
$f(1,n)=1$

$m=2$:
$f(2,n)=(3n+4)/4$

$m=3$:
$f(3,n)=(5n^2+19n+15)/15$

$m=4$:
$f(4,n)=(35n^3+255n^2+550n+336)/336$

$m=5$:
$f(5,n)=(63n^4+742n^3+3003n^2+4832n+2520)/2520$

$m=6$:
$f(6,n)=(77n^5+1330n^4+8575n^3+25410n^2+33908n+15840)/15840$

$m=7$:
$f(7,n)=(143n^6+3399n^5+31790n^4+148215n^3+358487n^2+418926n+180180)/180180$

We have as leading terms $n^{(m-1)}\cdot(m+1)/m!/2$.

These sums don't exhibit the odd/even behavior showing linear factors in the case of even $m$.
So we shouldn't rely on this feature at all.

There is no sequence on http://www.oeis.org

for $[1,3,5,35,63,77,143,\ldots]$ and $[1,4,15,336,2520,15840,180180,\ldots]$.

These sums have again a constant term equalling 1, the hypergeometric representation hint should still hold.

Answer (score 4):

Here's almost a solution.  Let the symmetric group $S_3$ act on the set of triples $\{(i,j,k)\mid 1\le i,j,k\le n\}$.  Let $f(i,j,k)$ denote the product of binomial coefficients being summed.  Note that $f$ is symmetric, so $f(i',j',k')=f(i,j,k)$ if $(i',j',k')$ and $(i,j,k)$ are in the same $S_3$ orbit.  Thus $f$ actually defines a function on the orbits.  The sum you are after is the sum of $f$ over all orbits.  This is an application of the [cycle index formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index).

Since the cycle index polynomial of $S_3$ is $\frac16(a_1^3+3a_2a_1+2a_3)$, we get your sum by evaluating this polynomial at $a_k=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i+m-1}{m-1}^k$.

The sum $a_1$ can be done by hand:
$$a_1=\frac{n+1}{m}\binom{m+n}{m-1}.$$
The other two are not so simple (since, for example, when $i=j$ you get the square of the corresponding binomial coefficient).  For fixed $m$, you can get a closed form (see below for $m=2$), but for general $m,n$ Mathematica gives
$$a_2=\frac{\Gamma (1-2 m)}{\Gamma (1-m)^2}-\binom{m+n}{m-1}^2 \,
   _3F_2(1,m+n+1,m+n+1;n+2,n+2;1)$$
and
$$\begin{multline}a_3=\frac{\left(1-\frac{m}{2}\right)_{-m} (m+1)_{-m}}{(1)_{-m}
   \left(\frac{m}{2}+1\right)_{-m}}-\\ \binom{m+n}{m-1}^3 \,
   _4F_3(1,m+n+1,m+n+1,m+n+1;n+2,n+2,n+2;1).
\end{multline}$$
Unfortunately, these expressions are indeterminate; I have not yet been able to coax a useful form out of Mathematica.

In the special case $m=2$, here are the closed forms:
$$\begin{align}
a_1=&\frac{1}{2} (n+1) (n+2) \\
a_2=&\frac{1}{6} (n+1) (n+2) (2 n+3) \\
a_3=&\frac{1}{4} (n+1)^2 (n+2)^2 \\
\frac16(a_1^3+3a_2a_1+2a_3)=&\frac{1}{48} (n+1)^2 (n+2)^2 (n+3) (n+4)
\end{align}$$

This gives the following values for small $n$ (which are easily verified to agree with the given summation):
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \\
\hline
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 15 \\
 2 & 90 \\
 3 & 350 \\
 4 & 1050 \\
 5 & 2646 \\
\end{array}

Comment: Could you please show how your indices run exactly in your distinct indices sum? And additionally compute e.g. with $m=2$ and $n=2$ that sum and the original sum?

Comment: @andre Thanks, I'd made a sign error.  The cycle index formula is the way to go; I added the $m=2$ case to the post.

Answer (score 3):

Let $m, n, s$ stand for any positive integers. In following discussion, we will assume $m$ is given.
Let $[n] = \{\; 0, 1, \ldots, n \;\}$  and define

$$a(n) = \binom{m-1+n}{m-1}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
f_s(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n a(n)^s
$$

The sum $\mathcal{S}$ we want  can be rewritten as

$$\mathcal{S} = \sum_{0 \le i\le j \le k \le n} a(i)a(j)a(k)$$

Start with any triple $(i,j,k)$ appear in above sum, if we reorder them, they will generate every element of $[n]^3$ at least once. In general,

1. if $i \ne j \ne k$, it will generate 6 distinct triples.
2. If two indices coincides, say $i = j \ne k$ or $i \ne j = k$, it will generate three distinct triples.
3. If $i = j = k$, there is only one distinct triples.

As a consequence of this, we find

$$\begin{align}
6 \mathcal{S} &= f_1(n)^3 + (6-3) f_1(n)f_2(n) + (6-3-1)f_3(n)\\
\iff
\mathcal{S} &= \frac16\big( f_1(n)^3 + 3 f_1(n)f_2(n) + 2f_3(n)\big)
\end{align}
$$
Our task reduces to the computation of $f_1(n)$, $f_2(n)$ and $f_3(n)$.

For $f_1(n)$, it is easy. Since the OGF for $a(n)$ is

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n) z^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{m-1+n}{m-1} z^n = \frac{1}{(1-z)^m}$$
The OCF for $f_1(n)$ will be equal to

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_1(n) z^n = \frac{1}{(1-z)(1-z)^{m}} =
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{m+1}}$$
This leads to $\displaystyle\;f_1(n) = \binom{m+n}{m}\;$.

For other $f_s(n)$ with $s > 1$, we will use the fact $a(n)$, as a function of $n$, is a polynomial in $n$ with degree $m-1$. This means $a(n)^s$ itself is a polynomial in $n$ with degree $s(m-1)$ and hence satisfies a linear recurrence relation of degree $s(m-1)+1$. Translate this into OCF, we find

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)^s z^n = \frac{B_s(z)}{(1-z)^{s(m-1)+1}}$$
for some polynomial $B_s(z)$ with degree $\le s(m-1)$. We can backout the coefficients of $B_s(z)$ by comparing the two sides of following relations
$$B_s(z) = (1-z)^{s(m-1)+1} \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)^s z^s\right)$$
The end result is
$$B_s(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{s(m-1)} b_s(n) z^n
\;\text{ with }\;
b_s(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{s(m-1)+1}{k} a(n-k)^s
$$

As a result, the OGF for $f_s(n)$ is

$$ \frac{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{s(m-1)} b_s(n) z^n}{(1-z)^{s(m-1)+2}}
\quad\implies\quad
f_s(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{s(m-1)}b_s(k)\binom{s(m-1)+1+n-k}{s(m-1)+1}
$$

With a little bit of algebra, one can simplify $b_2(n)$ and $b_3(n)$ as

$$\left\{\begin{align}
b_2(n) &= \binom{m-1}{n}^2\\
b_3(n) &= \sum_{k=\max(0,n-m+1)}^{\min(n,m-1)} \binom{m-1}{k}^2\binom{m-1+k}{n}\binom{2m-2-k}{2m-2-n}
\end{align}\right.$$
and in above sum, $b_2(n)$ and $b_3(n)$, terminate earlier at $m-1$ and $2(m-1)$ respectively.

As a final summary, we have

$$
\mathcal{S} = \frac16\big( f_1^3 + 3 f_1f_2 + 2f_3\big)
\quad\text{ with }\quad
\left\{\begin{align}
f_1 &= \binom{m+n}{m}\\
f_2 &= \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} b_2(k)\binom{2m-1+n-k}{2m-1}\\
f_3 &= \sum_{k=0}^{2m-2}b_3(k)\binom{3m-2+n-k}{3m-2}\\
\end{align}\right.
$$
Using this, one can compute $S$ for small $m$ as a polynomial in $n$.

- $m = 1$, $S = \binom{n+3}{3}$.
- $m = 2$, $S = \binom{n+4}{4}\binom{n+2}{2}$.
- $m = 3$, $S = \binom{n+5}{5}\frac{35n^4+294n^3+844n^2+969n+378}{378}$.
- $m = 4$, $S = \binom{n+6}{6}\binom{n+4}{4}\frac{35n^2+205n+168}{168}$.

Answer (score 0):

A second answer from me, the first double/triple sum free version,
verified up to a certain degree.

```
display2d : false;

for n : 0 thru 50 do block(
        print(n),
for m : 0 thru 50 do block(
        mylhs : sum(sum(sum(
                    1
                    *binomial(i+m,m)
                    *binomial(j+m,m)
                    *binomial(k+m,m)
        ,k,j,n),j,i,n),i,0,n),
        myrhs : 0,
        myrhs : myrhs + (
                    1
                    *binomial(n+m+1,m+1)
                    *binomial(n+m+1,m+1)
                    *binomial(n+m+1,m+1)
        ),
        myrhs : myrhs - sum(
                    1
                    *binomial(i+m,m)
                    *binomial(i+m,m+1)
                    *binomial(n+m+1,m+1)
        ,i,0,n),
        myrhs : myrhs - sum(
                    1
                    *binomial(i+m,m)
                    *binomial(i+m,m+1)
                    *binomial(i+m+1,m+1)
        ,i,0,n),
        res : mylhs/myrhs,
        if (res # 1) then block(
                print(n,m,"|",res)
        )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

This computation is a generalization of the one at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313543/).

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\sum_{0\le q_1 \le q_2 \le \cdots \le q_k \le n}
\prod_{p=1}^k {q_p+m-1\choose m-1}.$$

As pointed out elsewhere in the thread this is
$$\left.Z(S_k)(Q_0+Q_1+Q_2+\cdots+Q_n)\right|_{Q_p={p+m-1\choose m-1}}$$
where $Z(S_k)$ is the cycle index of the symmetric group.

The OGF of this cycle index is
$$G(w) = \exp\left(
a_1 w + a_2 \frac{w^2}{2} + a_3 \frac{w^3}{3} + \cdots
\right).$$

Doing the substitution we obtain
$$H(w) = \exp\left(
\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{w^l}{l} 
\sum_{p=0}^n {p+m-1\choose m-1}^l\right)
\\ = \exp\left(\sum_{p=0}^n 
\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{w^l}{l} 
{p+m-1\choose m-1}^l\right)
\\ = \exp\left(\sum_{p=0}^n 
\log\frac{1}{1-w{p+m-1\choose m-1}}\right)
= \prod_{p=0}^n \frac{1}{1-w{p+m-1\choose m-1}}.$$

This could have been obtained by inspection.

We thus require
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=0} \frac{1}{w^{k+1}}
\prod_{p=0}^n \frac{1}{1-w{p+m-1\choose m-1}} \; dw.$$

We need to convert the product term into a sum using partial fractions
by residues. We re-write it as follows:

$$\prod_{p=0}^n {p+m-1\choose m-1}^{-1}
\prod_{p=0}^n \frac{1}{1/{p+m-1\choose m-1}-w}
\\ = (-1)^{n+1} \prod_{p=0}^n {p+m-1\choose m-1}^{-1}
\prod_{p=0}^n \frac{1}{w-1/{p+m-1\choose m-1}}.$$

Extracting the residues we find
$$(-1)^{n+1} \prod_{p=0}^n {p+m-1\choose m-1}^{-1}
\sum_{p=0}^n \frac{1}{w-1/{p+m-1\choose m-1}} \\ \times
\prod_{q=0,\; q\ne p}^{n} 
\frac{1}{1/{p+m-1\choose m-1}-1/{q+m-1\choose m-1}}.$$

Prepare to extract coefficients with
$$(-1)^{n} \prod_{p=0}^n {p+m-1\choose m-1}^{-1}
\sum_{p=0}^n \frac{{p+m-1\choose m-1}}{1-w{p+m-1\choose m-1}}
\prod_{q=0,\; q\ne p}^{n} 
\frac{{p+m-1\choose m-1}}{1-{p+m-1\choose m-1}/{q+m-1\choose m-1}}$$

to obtain
$$(-1)^{n} \sum_{p=0}^n {p+m-1\choose m-1}^{k}
\prod_{q=0,\; q\ne p}^{n} 
\frac{{p+m-1\choose m-1}}{{q+m-1\choose m-1}-{p+m-1\choose m-1}}$$

for a final answer of
$$(-1)^{n} \sum_{p=0}^n {p+m-1\choose m-1}^{k+n}
\prod_{q=0,\; q\ne p}^{n} 
\frac{1}{{q+m-1\choose m-1}-{p+m-1\choose m-1}}.$$

**Remark.** We use the cycle index directly if a polynomial in $n$ and
$m$ is desired.

For example when $k=3$ we obtain the cycle index
$$Z(S_3) =
\frac{1}{6} a_1^3 + \frac{1}{2} a_1 a_2 + \frac{1}{3} a_3.$$

Substitution then yields
$$\frac{1}{6} \left(\sum_{p=0}^n {p+m-1\choose m-1}\right)^3
+ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{p=0}^n {p+m-1\choose m-1}
\sum_{p=0}^n {p+m-1\choose m-1}^2
\\ + \frac{1}{3} \sum_{p=0}^n {p+m-1\choose m-1}^3.$$

Once we fix $m$ we get polynomials  in $n$ e.g. in the above case with
$k=3$ obtain for $m=1$

$$1/6\, \left( n+3 \right)  \left( n+2 \right)  \left( n+1 \right)$$

and for $m=4$

$${\frac { \left( n+6 \right)  \left( n+5 \right)  \left( 35\,{n}^{2}+205
\,n+168 \right)  \left( n+4 \right) ^{2} \left( n+3 \right) ^{2} \left(
n+2 \right) ^{2} \left( n+1 \right) ^{2}}{2903040}}.$$

Similarly when $k=4$ the cycle index is
$$Z(S_4) =
1/24\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}+1/4\,a_{{2}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}+1/3\,a_{{3}}a_{{1}}+1/8\,{
a_{{2}}}^{2}+1/4\,a_{{4}}$$

and we get e.g. for $m=2$
$${\frac { \left( n+5 \right)  \left( n+4 \right)  \left( n+3 \right)
 \left( n+2 \right)  \left( n+1 \right)  \left( 15\,{n}^{3}+75\,{n}^{2}+
110\,n+48 \right) }{5760}}.$$

Finally observe that when $m=1$ the substituted cycle index becomes
$$H(w) = \exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1}\frac{w^l}{l} (n+1)\right)
= \exp\left((n+1)\log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)
= \frac{1}{(1-w)^{n+1}}.$$

Doing the coefficient extraction we obtain the special case formula
$${k+n\choose n} = {n+k\choose k}.$$

Indeed when $k=5$ and $m=1$ we find by substituting into the cycle index
the result
$${\frac { \left( n+5 \right)  \left( n+4 \right)  \left( n+3 \right)
 \left( n+2 \right)  \left( n+1 \right) }{120}}.$$

Additional exploration of  this problem may be undertaken  by using the
following Maple code.

```
A :=
proc(n, m, k)
    option remember;
    local iter;

    iter :=
    proc(l)
        if nops(l) = 0 then
            add(iter([q]), q=0..n)
        elif nops(l) < k then
            add(iter([op(l), q]), q=op(-1, l)..n)
        else
            mul(binomial(m-1+l[q], m-1), q=1..k);
        fi;
    end;

    iter([]);
end;

EX :=
proc(n, m, k)
    option remember;

    (-1)^n*add(binomial(p+m-1,m-1)^(k+n)*
               mul(1/(binomial(q+m-1,m-1)-binomial(p+m-1,m-1)),
                   q=0..p-1)*
               mul(1/(binomial(q+m-1,m-1)-binomial(p+m-1,m-1)),
                   q=p+1..n),
               p=0..n);
end;


pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
local p, s;
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

P :=
proc(m, k)
    local sl, ind, onesub;

    sl := [];

    for ind to k do
        onesub := sum((mul(p+q, q=1..m-1)/(m-1)!)^ind, p=0..n);
        sl := [op(sl), a[ind]=onesub];
    od;

    factor(subs(sl, pet_cycleind_symm(k)));
end;
```